# Prestashop Performance Issue

Tags: performance, prestashop, web-hosting, prestashop-1.5, prestashop-1.6

Hi one of my client has a website for which she has used prestashop, but she is facing alot of problem with respect to the performance. We actually deleted the cache and used the smart cache method for increasing the performance but it was still of no use. I'm totally new to prestashop, i tried checking with respect to the server bandwidth and we were utilizing hardly 5% of the bandwidth provided. So we asked the previous developer of the website and he was had no clue what was happening. Could you please help me out in solving the performance issue thanks in advance.

Website URL : [www.mithrasaree.com](http://www.mithrasaree.com)

Answer (score 4):

In administration panel of `Prestashop`, go to `Preferences` > `Performances`.

For `Smarty` :

- `Force compilation` : No
- `Cache` : Yes

For `Cache` :

- `Use cache` : Yes
- `Cache system` : Memcached (if you have installed it, otherwise `File System` that I haven't tested)

If you haven't installed `memcached`, install it, it can improve your website performance.

- Linux (apt) : `apt-get install memcached`
- Linux (yum) : `yum install memcached`

Once `memcached` is installed, restart your webserver.

Answer (score 0):

Everything is correct what @kmass suggested however i suggest you to enable all the options under the CCC (Combine, Compress and Cache) form in Performance Tab aswell.

BR's

Comment: I had some problem with Javascript CCC (if I remember well), so I won't suggest it. But CCC options work well for a lot of people.

Comment: CCC in prestashop is a joke. This is making a different file for each page. So the user will load jQuery and all the plugins under a different name  every time he changes a page… this is an absolute non-sense.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys for helping me with the problem, i had enabled and used the options provided by you but the problem was none of those. The actual problem was that my client was uploading images of very high resolution which she captured using her DSLR camera.